# Error in Python: missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, typeerror, positional-argument

I'm not so good with python and I keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: demand_curve() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pb'
```

And this is my code:

```
P,c,Q,y,pb,N,X,pf,t=sp.symbols('P c Q y pb N X pf t')

def demand_curve(c,Q,y,pb):
    demand = (c.log(Q)-(-4.507+(0.841*y)+(0.2775*pb)))/(-0.397) 
    return demand

Q_num = np.linspace(0,100,100)

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.set_ylabel('P')
ax.set_xlabel('E')

ax.plot(demand_curve(Q_num, 50, 2), Q_num,label='E (a=100,b=2)')

#legend:
ax.legend(loc='upper right', frameon=False)
ax.set(xlim=(0,100))
ax.set(ylim=(0,60))
```

I don't really understand what is the problem, can someone help me?

Comment: Well your function `demand_curve()` takes 4 argument (c ,Q, y and pb) and when you call the function, you only provide 3 of them : Q_num, 50 and 2. So there's one argument missing : "pb".

Answer (score 4):

When you declare your function you do this :

```py
def demand_curve(c,Q,y,pb):
    ...
```

So you have four parameters `c`, `Q`, `y` and `pb`, later in the code you call it using :

```py
demand_curve(Q_num, 50, 2)
```

So in the way you call it you have

- c = Q_num
- Q = 50
- y = 2
- pb = Nothing at all

And python don't like this so you should provide and additional value when you call this function or provide a default value for the last parameter for example :

```py
def demand_curve(c,Q,y,pb = "a default value"):
    ...
```

Comment: Well thats another question, by `log()` do you mean the `math` logarithmic function ? because you are trying to call it on a `numpy` array, which does not have that kind of method. You can however call `np.log(c)`. See the [numpy.log()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.log.html) doc.

Comment: I'm will try it like you suggested. I'm a little confused because it makes sense to write it like ```np.log(c)```but this is a task for a school project and the professor said we have to use ```c.log()``` even though I don't think it makes sense

Comment: Perhaps `np` should be the first parameter: `demand_curve(np, Q_num, 50, 2)` Now you have four parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing all the arguments value when you call you function "demand_curve". Your function "demand_curve(c,Q,y,pb)" required 4 positional arguments but you give only 3 at "demand_curve(Q_num, 50, 2)".